# Windows 8 Store - dropdown on "Your apps" is duplicated

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, windows-store-app

In my Windows 8, when I open Store, right click, go to "Your apps", the dropdown has duplicated options for my PC. See below.

[image]

Why is that? How can I fix this and have it display only 1 option in the dropdown, for my PC?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried rebooting yet?  What _have_ you tried already?

Comment: Why does this bother you?

Comment: @techie007, I tried rebooting, no difference.

Comment: @Ramhound, this is inconsistent and wrong, and bothers me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/windows-store-install-apps-five-pcs

To remove a PC from your account

1.
On the Start screen, tap or click Store to open the Windows Store.

2.
Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Settings.
(If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click Settings.)

3.
Tap or click Your account. If you haven't signed in to the Windows Store, sign in using your Microsoft account.

4.
Under Your PCs, tap or click Remove next to the PC you want to remove from your account.

Comment: you should mark this as answer.